# Authorize(Roles = "Admin") not working on FormAuthentication for SSO In Mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In form authentication the  `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` not working.

Here is the web.config:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" />
     <authentication mode="Forms">          
          <forms  defaultUrl="~/Account/Login" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" domain=".xyz.com"  path="/"/>
        </authentication>
        <machineKey validationKey="395BB0DAFA02BA520EDB43E7EDF06BBFD72FC13A5209243270539E01074B0EA4" decryptionKey="037D2C9D97979D8D810F4A6A2B9337BD181F32167735F2E0" validation="SHA1"/>
```

Here is the `Application_AuthenticateRequest` in Global.asax

```
    protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            try
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

                CustomPrincipalSerializeModel serializeModel = serializer.Deserialize<CustomPrincipalSerializeModel>(authTicket.UserData);

                CustomPrincipal newUser = new CustomPrincipal(authTicket.Name);
                newUser.UserID  = serializeModel.UserID;
                newUser.FirstName = serializeModel.FirstName;
                newUser.LastName = serializeModel.LastName;
                newUser.ProfilePicture = serializeModel.ProfilePicture;
                newUser.UserCode = serializeModel.UserCode;
                newUser.UserEmail = serializeModel.UserEmail;
                newUser.UserType = serializeModel.UserType;
                newUser.Fk_Parent = serializeModel.Fk_Parent;
                newUser.CompanyID = serializeModel.CompanyID;
                newUser.isSASS = serializeModel.isSASS;
                newUser.Commission = serializeModel.Commission;
                newUser.CommissionManager = serializeModel.CommissionManager;
                newUser.ISACount = serializeModel.ISACount;

                HttpContext.Current.User = newUser;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.User = null;
            }
        }
    }

    interface ICustomPrincipal : IPrincipal
    {
        int UserID { get; set; }
        string FirstName { get; set; }
        string LastName { get; set; }
        string ProfilePicture { get; set; }
        Guid UserCode { get; set; }
        string UserEmail { get; set; }
        int UserType { get; set; }
        int Fk_Parent { get; set; }
        string CompanyID { get; set; }
        Nullable<bool> isSASS { get; set; }
        double? Commission { get; set; }
        double? CommissionManager { get; set; }
        Nullable<int> ISACount { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomPrincipal : ICustomPrincipal
    {
        public IIdentity Identity { get; private set; }
        public bool IsInRole(string role) {
            string inRole = string.Empty;
            inRole =Enum.GetName(typeof(UserType), UserType);

            if (inRole == role)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }

        public CustomPrincipal(string email)
        {
            this.Identity = new GenericIdentity(email);
        }

        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string ProfilePicture { get; set; }
        public Guid UserCode { get; set; }
        public string UserEmail { get; set; }
        public int UserType { get; set; }
        public int Fk_Parent { get; set; }
        public string CompanyID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> isSASS { get; set; }
        public double? Commission { get; set; }
        public double? CommissionManager { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ISACount { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomPrincipalSerializeModel
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string ProfilePicture { get; set; }
        public Guid UserCode { get; set; }
        public string UserEmail { get; set; }
        public int UserType { get; set; }
        public int Fk_Parent { get; set; }
        public string CompanyID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> isSASS { get; set; }
        public double? Commission { get; set; }
        public double? CommissionManager { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ISACount { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the controller:

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Admin,SubAdmin")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
        ////
        }
```

the problem is that when i use `<authentication mode="Forms">` in web.config then Authorize Role is not working.

I have two different domain(one is suppose `xyz.com` and another one is `a.xyz.com`(subdomain))

Here i am passing the cookie value from one to another for accessing all the data.(sso)

The above code is in `xyz.com`.
the same code of `global.asax` is on the `a.xyz.com`
so How do i fix the problem.Both are in Mvc 5 c#.